# Defining properties that subclasses must implement

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I have a super class that needs some properties to be set to work properly.

I am looking for a way to force/notify/alert any subclass that it must set those properties, so any one that subclasses this super won't forget to do that.

What is the best practise for that?
(**I am coding Obj-c**)

Thanks
Shai

Comment: It sounds like there is a slight confusion between defining the property and setting it. Are you looking for a way to enforce the properties being set or a way to enforce that the subclasses each define that list of properties?

Comment: To enforce that the subclasses each define that list of properties, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a designated initializer of the form:

```
- (id)initWithProperty1:(Property1Type *)property1 property2:(Property2Type *)
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _property1 = property1;
        _property2 = property2;
    {
    return self;
}
```

Then you could override the standard initializer and force it to abort (kinda harsh), or have it log a message:

```
- (id)init
{
    NSLog(@"You must use the designated initializer.");
    return nil;
}
```

In the documentation for your class, be sure to state what the designated initializer is.